# Self.find method Active Model in Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm currently using an API and not a database, and I want to be as close as ActiveRecord, so I decided to go ahead and do exactly like this railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

So far, my save method works well, so I can save data to the API. My problem is with the edit, my find method seems to be the problem... Here is some code!

**Edit method in my controller**

```
  def edit
    @parking = Parking.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Whole model**

```
class Parking
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :address, :city, :longitude, :latitude, :contributor_name, :contributor_email

  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :city, :longitude, :latitude

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def self.find(id)
    parking           = Parse.get("Parking", id.to_s) // API Call

    name              = parking["name"]
    address           = parking["address"]
    city              = parking["city"]
    longitude         = parking["location"]["longitude"]
    latitude          = parking["location"]["latitude"]
    contributor_name  = parking["contributorName"]
    contributor_email = parking["contributorEmail"]

    return self
  end

  def save
    if (!valid?)
      return false
    else
      parking = Parse::Object.new("Parking")

      data =
      {
        :longitude => 40.0,
        :latitude  => -30.0
      }

      point = Parse::GeoPoint.new(data)

      parking["location"]         = point
      parking["name"]             = name
      parking["address"]          = address
      parking["city"]             = city
      parking["contributorName"]  = contributor_name
      parking["contributorEmail"] = contributor_email

      if (parking.save)
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

**Here is the error I currently get:**

```
undefined method `to_key' for Parking:Class
```

*Extracted source (around line #1):*

```
1: <%= form_for(@parking, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @parking.errors.any? %>
3:     <div class="alert alert-error fade in">
4:       <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>**
```

If anybody as suggestions, I'm open to any ideas really, I'm beginning with rails :)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

When I do in my controller edit method something like:

```
  def edit
    @parking = Parking.new
    @parking.name              = "foo"
    @parking.address           = "foo"
    @parking.city              = "foo"
    @parking.longitude         = "foo"
    @parking.latitude          = "foo"   
  end
```

My view load foo in every fields no problemo, so the problem is I must be doing something wrong with the find method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that your `find` method is a *class method* (by virtue of being 'self.find'), meaning it does not operate on an instance of the class and therefore has no knowledge of instance variables/methods such as `name`, `address` etc.

A better way to implement `find` is to instantiate a new instance of `Parking`, and populate it's variables, then return it e.g.

```
def self.find(id)
   raw = Parse.get("Parking", id.to_s)

   parking = Parking.new
   parking.name = raw["name"]
   #  etc for the others

   parking # Return the newly-created instance
end
```

This doesn't explain the 'undefined method' you're currently seeing, you may need to post up more detail to get an answer for that, particularly a full backtrace from the exception to see which bit of code is actually raising it.  From the information you've supplied I'd guess that something within the `Parse.get` method is causing it.

Comment: Oh great, that did work! Before going to bed yesterday, I did something similar, but I was doing the Parking.new in the controller and not in my class method (which I didn't like because it's not like ActiveRecord). Just before I accept this as the answer, can you tell me if it's a common practice to instantiate the current class in one of it's own class method like self.find? Is this how the find method in ActiveRecord works?

Comment: I can't say how ActiveRecord does it exactly, had a brief look but there are many layers of abstraction in there.  It is common for methods which operate on the collection (e.g. create, find etc) to be a class method of the Parking class, and use instance methods for save, update etc.